# embedding wxPython in VisualStudio 2005 C/C++ fails

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++, wxpython

When I try to embed python wx in C like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifdef _DEBUG
  #undef _DEBUG
  #include <Python.h>
  #define _DEBUG
#else
  #include <Python.h>
#endif

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  PyObject* pyModule;
  Py_Initialize();
  //_pyModule = PyImport_ImportModule("__main__");
  //_pyModule = PyImport_ImportModule("csi");
  pyModule = PyImport_ImportModule("wx");
  if(!pyModule)
    PyErr_Print();
  return 0;
}
```

it fails:

```
->Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-ansi\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
  from wx._core import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-ansi\wx\_core.py", line 4, in <module>
  import _core_
  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

could be a problem with msvc*90.dll files?

I am using VS2005, Python 2.7, wxPython 2.8.12.1 (ansi) for Python 2.7

Further MS VC++ 2008/2010 Redistributables are installed.

thanks for help.

Comment: Why are you doing that? You could just use wxWidgets instead since it's actually C++.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution:

it is a Manifest problem. Thanks to Microsof dll-hell...

This helps:

```
//_core_.pyd ImportError
// _core_.pyd is in fact a dll. it can be renamed.
// The problem is that _core_.pyd depends on some Microsoft.VC90.CRT libraries
//this dependency must be added to make it work
#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT' version='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' language='*'\"")
```

Comment: This really works, I use a python module that is a extension, when I launch the python interpreter on windows and import that module, there is no error. But when I use this module in a project that uses boost python, `boost::python::import` (which uses `PyImport_ImportModule`) will always throw import error.