# wxPython Import Error: DLL load failed

Tags: python, wxpython

Installed wxpython 2.8-unicode with Python 2.7 on Windows 7 32-bit.

During import, below Import Error occurs:

> Traceback
>
> ...\python27\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx_core.py in < module >()
>
> import _core_
>
> Import Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Reinstalling the Python extension was not helpful.

It's somewhat unexpected to get the error after installing the extension with the installer. If someone who had the same problem and resolved issue, it would be very nice for me to get some help. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979486/py2exe-win32api-pyc-importerror-dll-load-failed

Comment: Would the discussion be applied here when the answer states that "when the package was built on Vista but executed on XP"?

Comment: i am not sure, that's why i posted it as comment

Answer (score 0):

There are several suggestions at ["import wx" fails after installation of wxPython on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316325/import-wx-fails-after-installation-of-wxpython-on-windows-xp) such as to install the MSVC 2008 redistributable, or to reboot your computer.

EDIT: I've also found this link helpful: [embedding wxPython in VisualStudio 2005 C/C++ fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207513/embedding-wxpython-in-visualstudio-2005-c-c-fails)

I'm having the same problem, and I'm trying to figure out the correct version of the MSVC 2008 redistributable, and where to put the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me, just try it out.

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select('3.0')
import wx
```